# Change eclipse menuitem color

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, plugins, swt

I would like to change some `menuitems` color ,for example yellow, dynamically with my plugin.
is it possible?

More details:
Lets say I wanna change the `file->import menuitem` to yellow, which class is responsible for that?
For simpleness, if I got SWT window, calculater with File menu in it, how to change the `File->exit menuItem` to yellow when I press or do something in this calculator windows??
thanks in advance

Comment: Have you actually seen colored menu items in any application? It's quite possible that SWT doesn't support that simply because the underlying windowing systems don't either.

Answer (score 1):

Any menu-related color settings are OS-dependent, since SWT is based on native GUI implementation (as [Kos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/399317/kos) alludes to in the comment).

This [thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.swt/msg40689.html) asks for the "inactive color":

> I don't think there's a `SWT.COLOR_...` available for disabled menu texts, it's the OSs that colors these texts.
>   I don't know if the OSs provide a way for accessing this color programmatically.

This [thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.swt/msg35295.html) want to add color to a popup menu, and the best solution is...

> I think your best bet is #2, that way you could put (for instance) a Table
>   widget with no columns in the pop-up, which would allow you customize the
>   item appearances however you like.

- [emulated tooltip snippet (.java)](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet125.java?view=co)
- [Table custom draw article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-CustomDrawingTableAndTreeItems/index.html)

[image]