# How to highlight MenuItem programmatically in SWT

Tags: swt

I open a context menu programmatically. Now additionally I would like to highlight the first menu entry.

This highlighting happens when I move with the mouse over the context menu or press the arrow keys on the keyboard. I am interested how I can trigger this programmatically.

I know the API of `MenuItem` does not offer this feature out of the box. So I tried to fire some `MouseEvent`s of the type `MouseOver` and `MouseHover`, but without any success.

Has anybody an idea how to implement this feature?

Comment: Firing events doesn't do anything to the actual native control. If there is no API for this it is very unlikely that it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can change menuitem highlight colors, I haven't seen any previous example before. Look at this though: [Change eclipse menuitem color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171576/change-eclipse-menuitem-color)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simulate what the user does and if you happen to know the location of the menu item, you can use `Display#setCursorLocation()` to position the mouse pointer over the menu item.

Note however, that if and how a menu item is highlighted is platform specific.

You should not use this method other than for demonstration of test purposes. If your application needs to highlight or preselect an entry in a list of choices, 
you should probably use another widget. If you more describe your use case, we may be able to find a suitable widget.